# I am converting dictionary to dataframe in python and output has changed

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am converting dictionary to dataframe in python and output has changed. Did i write anything wrong here.
In dictionary output we have source id for 1 time but after converted to dataframe source id coming 4 times but i want parsed_address should be multivalue. I want dictionary output same in dataframe only.

**Dictionary Output:**

**dic--->**

```
{
   "source_id":123,
   "parsed_address":[
      {
         "address_type":"Primary",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"18 Atherton",
               "address_line_2":"nan"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_type":"directory",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"130 E Chapman Ave Apt 312",
               "address_line_2":"nan"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_type":"home",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"9722 Walnut St",
               "address_line_2":"nan"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_type":"work",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"1325 S Grand Ave",
               "address_line_2":"nan"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**DataFrame Output:**

```
  [
   {
      "parsed_address":{
         "address_type":"Primary",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"18 Atherton",
               "address_line_2":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "source_id":"90353002"
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":{
         "address_type":"directory",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"130 E Chapman Ave Apt 312",
               "address_line_2":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "source_id":"90353002"
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":{
         "address_type":"home",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"9722 Walnut St",
               "address_line_2":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "source_id":"90353002"
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":{
         "address_type":"work",
         "address":[
            {
               "address_line_1":"1325 S Grand Ave",
               "address_line_2":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "source_id":"90353002"
   }
]
```

**code**

```
print("dic--->",dic)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print("df4--->",df4)

Converted dictionary to dataframe and output has changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is recycling of scalar values.
This behavior is also why you can assign a scalar to a new column and the number of rows stays the same.
You can wrap the parsed address into another list to get a single row.